# TSV file into 2d array - java

Tags: java

I have a tsv txt file containing data in 3 rows.

It looks like:

```
HG  sn  FA  
PC  2   16:0
PI  1   18:0
PS  3   20:0
PE  2   24:0
        26:0
        16:1
        18:2
```

I want to read this file into a 2 dimensional array in java.

But i get an error all the time, no matter what i try.

```
File file = new File("table.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        final int maxLines = 100;
        String[][] resultArray = new String[maxLines][];
        int linesCounter = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine() && linesCounter < maxLines) {
            resultArray[linesCounter] = scanner.nextLine().split("\t");
            linesCounter++;
        }

        System.out.print(resultArray[1][1]);
```

I keep getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at exercise.exercise2.main(exercise2.java:31)
```

Line 31 is

```
 System.out.print(resultArray[1][1]);
```

I cannot find any reasons why this error keeps emerging

Comment: Don't do that. Read it into a `List<MyObject>` where `MyObject` contains the data. This is an OO language, use it. To read the file use a read CSV library - such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Arrays indexes are zero-based. The first cell of you array is resultArray[0][0]. If it is a TSV, so you must split on tabs ("\\t") instead of minus signs ("-").

Comment: The split is on "-" delimeter and I don't see "-" in your input file anywhere. Make delimeter as (space) or (tab) and it should work.

Comment: Yes i have corrected that, but when i try to call resultArray[2][5] i get: exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsexception: 5

Comment: Note that if you say `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultArray[1]));`, this will tell you exactly what's in the array.

Comment: @KlausJoeChristiansen Why would there be a `5`? There are only 3 items in the TSV file.

Comment: Your code works for me, the difference  is file you used. Be sure that you have tab separated file. The easiest way to check, open file in Notepad++ and replace all `\t` with `[tab]`. Sounds like file is broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case I would use Java 7 `Files.readAllLines`.

Something like:

```
String[][] resultArray;

List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("table.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

//lines.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null)); // <- remove empty lines

resultArray = new String[lines.size()][]; 

for(int i =0; i<lines.size(); i++){
  resultArray[i] = lines.get(i).split("\t"); //tab-separated
}
```

Output:

```
[[HG, sn  FA  ], [PC, 2, 16:0], [PI, 1, 18:0], [PS, 3, 20:0], [PE, 2, 24:0], [, , 26:0], [, , 16:1], [, , 18:2]]
```

And this is the file (press `edit` and grab the content, it should be tab separated):

HG  sn  FA
PC  2   16:0
PI  1   18:0
PS  3   20:0
PE  2   24:0
        26:0
        16:1
        18:2

**[EDIT]**

To get `16:1`:

```
System.out.println(root[6][2]);
```

Comment: What's with the character group? Why not `\t++`?

Comment: Actually If he wants 3 values, enough to use `\t`

Comment: Nothing to do with the number of values the OP wants, it's whether there might be multiple separators.

Comment: The difference between `\t` and `\t+` is that in the first case he will get 3 values on the final line and in the second case he will get 2 values.

Comment: @BobDalgleish  yep, and we want to make fixed column size, this i a reason that I used `\t` only

Comment: Okay i have tried your way, i am getting the same outputs. but how to i get for example just the output 16:1 ?